# 'super' object has no attribute 'objects' Python Django

Tags: python, django

you need to get the `filter` using the `get_related_filter` class method

**views**

```
modelPath = 'Money.models'
app_model = importlib.import_module(modelPath)
cls = getattr(app_model, 'Money')
related_result = cls().get_related_filter(search_query='search_query')
```

**models.py**

```
class Money(models.Model):
    money = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, blank=True, default=0, decimal_places=2)   

    def get_related_filter(self, **kwargs):
        results = super(Money, self).objects.filter(Q(money__icontains=kwargs['search_query']))
        return results

    def __str__(self):
        return self.money
```

why gives `'super' object has no attribute 'objects' Python Django`, and does not return `filter`

Comment: Why don't you simply use `Money.objects.filter(...)`. The error means that the super class of `Money`, the `Model` has no `objects`.

Comment: Does the models.Money class have an attribute called 'objects'? I'm guessing not.

Comment: @NicholasHunter: yes, since the metaclass of `Model` (the `ModelBase`) will populate that, given you do not specify another manager.

Answer (score 1):

It makes no sense to work with `super(Money, self)` for two reasons:

1. this proxy object will resolve to `Model`, but `Model` nor it parents have an `objects` attribute; and
2. even if that was the case, you can only access `.objects` on a model *class*, not the instance.

You thus can filter with:

```
class Money(models.Model):
    money = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, blank=True, default=0, decimal_places=2)   

    def get_related_filter(self, search_query, **kwargs):
        return Money.objects.filter(money__icontains=search_query)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.money)
```

The `__str__` is also supposed to return a string, not a decimal, so you should return `str(self.money)`, not `self.money`.